# Possible to secure mint function with secret string instead of whitelist?

Tags: solidity, mint

I want that only whitelisted users are able to use my mint function.

I have already a working solution with a whitelist which I will post below. But this solution requires one transaction for every user I want to add to the whitelist.

Now I was thinking about another solution with passing a secret string as an argument to the mint function.

Am I right in assuming that it is not possible to keep this string a secret? It will show up in the transaction details right?

I have already tested it but on Etherscan at the bottom of the transaction there is no option to decode input data when viewing the transaction details: https://sepolia.etherscan.io/tx/0x6056bf5155afb7252596c7d1ffecbce794908390338720c5de687ca551dc01ab

Here is my code with the secret string:

```
uint256 private id;

    function mint(
        address account,
        string calldata tokenUri,
        string calldata secret,
        bytes memory data
    ) public {
        bytes32 secretHash = keccak256(bytes(secret));
        bytes32 desiredHash = keccak256(bytes("test12345"));
        require(secretHash == desiredHash, "Not correct secret string");
        _mint(account, id, 1, data);
        _tokenURIs[id] = tokenUri;
        id++;
    }
```

And here is my working solution with a whitelist:

```
uint256 private id;

    function mint(
        address account,
        string calldata tokenUri,
        bytes memory data
    ) public {
        require(whitelist[msg.sender], "Account is not in whitelist");
        _mint(account, id, 1, data);
        _tokenURIs[id] = tokenUri;
        id++;
    }

    mapping(address => bool) public whitelist;

    function addToWhitelist(
        address[] calldata toAddAddresses
    ) external onlyOwner {
        for (uint i = 0; i < toAddAddresses.length; i++) {
            whitelist[toAddAddresses[i]] = true;
        }
    }

    function removeFromWhitelist(
        address[] calldata toRemoveAddresses
    ) external onlyOwner {
        for (uint i = 0; i < toRemoveAddresses.length; i++) {
            delete whitelist[toRemoveAddresses[i]];
        }
    }
```

Comment: You wold need a secret string for each whitelisted address so the secret cannot be reused. Also, you would need to save the secret string in the contract as a hash or else I could be read.

Comment: either you can go with creating & storing hash of each secret in contract, & then asking user to provide their secret along with... but instead of this you can directly whitelist user in a mpping (address=>bool)& add a require in mint function to only allow whitelisted addresses... but in these both u have to make many trxns to either store secrets on contract or whitelisting each address.. if you want to avoid that you better use merkle tree concept

Comment: as a side comment (since it doesn't answer the question directly), you should investigate merkle trees and signed messages (where a minter admin acct signs a fixed msg + whitelisted addr offline) as potential solutions if you're looking for other ways to do this

Comment: Thanks for your tips! I will investigate merkle trees and signed messages...